# Combinatorics problem with n-words

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $x_{1},...x_{n}$ be different chars
I'm making words of length $n$, where $$n=3k, k\in \mathbb{N}$$
I have two questions 
1) how many different words are there, with all different characters, that don't contain the subword $$x_{i}x_{i+1}, i = {1,....,n-1}$$
2) how many words with exactly $3$ different chars are there such that every char appears exactly $k$ times and every subword of length k contains at least two different chars.

So i thought i would just use permutations but it was a no go for first one, so i'm thinking of using the rule of excluding but in not sure.
On second question i have no ideas, maybe there is a catch with $n=3k$ and there being exactly 3 different chars

Any help would be appreciated.
I give my thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1 just use inclusion-exclusion principle, with the properties - "$x_ix_{i+1}$" is a substring, and look for all the words that dont have any of those properties.

As for 2, Note that if you pick the 3 Chars then you can determine the number of words they can form, and then you need to subtract the number of words in which theres a subword of length $k$ which is formed by only one char, you could also compute that by inclusion exclusion, with the property - all the instances of char $x$ are consecutive.